# QWidgetAction Not Being Returned After QMenu Close

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

I have a `QPushButton` in a `QWidgetAction` in a `QMenu`. When the button is clicked, I want the action to trigger and the menu to close, returning which action was triggered. According to the docs, the widget itself must trigger the action directly.

Here's my code:

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu();
QWidgetAction *widgetAction = new QWidgetAction(menu);
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Finish");

widgetAction->setDefaultWidget(button);
menu->addAction(widgetAction);

connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), widgetAction, SLOT(trigger()));
connect(widgetAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), menu, SLOT(close())); //Menu won't close without this

QAction* selectedAction = menu->exec(mapToGlobal(ui->pushButton->pos()));
if(selectedAction != NULL)
{
    qDebug() << "no output from here";
}
```

However `selectedAction` always returns `NULL`. Regular `QAction`'s added to the menu automatically close the menu and return pointers to themselves. Why doesn't `QWidgetAction`?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `connect(widgetAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), menu, SLOT(close()));` not making any selection in the menu. I would just connect the signal of specific action triggered to the specific slot then.

Comment: @AlexanderVX What? I don't understand

Comment: You should not close the menu like that or you don't get the action from `exec()`. If you still do that do `connect(widgetAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(myClose()));` and create the slot `MyWidget::myClose() {doSomething(); menu->close();}`. I just cannot answer the question directly but know how to accomplish the task.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I don't want to call a function, I want to return which action was triggered. Like a regular `QAction`.

Comment: The reason I don't want to simply call another function is because I need access to certain top level widgets AND the widget in the menu. So I would like to work within the scope of the menu, like any other QAction.

Comment: I do it like that with assigning the lambda to the action and not even bother of nested widgets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719397/qt-slots-and-c11-lambda

Comment: I'm not using c++ 11. I'm not looking to operate ON the action. I need to identify the action that was called after exec returns and then interact with variables in that local scope. Simply put, an actual answer to my question....