# Qt: Is emitting signals in lamdas ok or it is bad style (and will it cause problems)

Tags: qt, c++11, lambda

Let's say I have Widget containing a `Button` and a `Spinbox`. When the Button is clicked I wish to emit the value of the Spinbox.

I see two possible ways to do this:
Either I can create a private member function

```
//...
connect(m_Button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &SomeWidget::emitSpinboxValue);
//...

SomeWidget::emitSpinboxValue() {
    emit spinboxValueChanged(m_Spinbox->value());
}
```

Or I can directly do that in a lambda:

```
//...
connect(m_Button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() { emit spinboxValueChanged(m_Spinbox->value()) });
//...
```

The lambda way looks neater (since I do not need to create a rather empty member function), but on the other hand seeing that `emit` in the lambda gives me a bad feeling in my gut.

So, is emitting signals in a lambda ok (and my gut oversensitive), or is it bad style (or do I even set myself up for some unexpected trouble in the future)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's fine

`emit` is an empty macro. A signal is a (tool generated) function, and it gets called in the same way as any other function. You've captured `this`, so you can call any member from the lambda as-if you were in a `SomeWidget` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally fine.  However, there is something wrong in your code:

```
connect(m_Button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() { emit spinboxValueChanged(m_Spinbox->value()) });
```

Must be:

```
//                                    Important!
//                                       vvvv
connect(m_Button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]() { 
    emit spinboxValueChanged(m_Spinbox->value()); 
});
```

You have to specify the object context for the functor to ensures that the functor will not get invoked if the object does not exist anymore.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719397/qt-slots-and-c11-lambda) for more information.

Comment: Given that the source is a button owned by the widget, the connection's lifetime is bounded by the widget's lifetime

Comment: @Caleth Yup. Still, it is a good thing to keep in mind if the lifetime of the `this` pointer of the lambda were not (safely) tied to the lifetime of the sender.